# How to call controller method from app.js laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I want to pass an object to my controller method AccepterDemande . So , I used axios to call the method from my app.js but I don't know if it's really work ? because I don't get any error but the method doesn't display the result .

```
var ListeRc= new Vue({

  el: '#rctable' ,



 data() {
            return {
                rcs: []
            } 

        },

  mounted : function(){
    console.log('mounted');
  },
  created() {
     this.listenerRc();
  } ,
  methods : {
     listenerRc(){
               e.channel('channelSup')
                .listen('EnvoyerDemande', (e) => {
                    this.rcs.push(e)  

                  })
     },
     accepter($index){
       axios.get('/response',{
        DateRc:this.rcs[$index].DateRc,
        Id:this.rcs[$index].id
       });
     }


 },
});
```

When I click on button I call the function Accepter($index); I test before if rcs[$index] work ; and yes It works .
this is my route :

```
Route::get('/response','SuperieurController@AccepterDemande');
```

and my SuperieurController :

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuperieurController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Superieur');
    }

    public function AccepterDemande(Request $request){
     dd($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in the inspector of your browser's dev tools if the request is going to the correct url and your params are the way you want them to be?

Comment: no , it doesn't change

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't change ? I was asking if your request is going towards the correct address if looking at your network stats... Which is super unlikely because you are going to /response which is another url than your Backend considering you are running on dev env, as these use different ports, right?